# Is it possible to run an application automatically on boot up as background service in J2me?

Tags: service, java-me, background, location

I wanted to develop Location Based Service in J2me which has to start automatically on Boot up & run as background service ,which will send periodic location to the server? How can i implement it on J2me ?

Any Suggestions,tips or examples will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Srizan, 
It is possible using the Application Settings.  You need to set the Auto Start setting to true in Application Settings.

Comment: Thanks Arjun for your reply. What i wanted to know is , is there any special permissions required from device manufactures for ex- Nokia or simply we can implement it ! I would be happy if you explain it on Detail with some example codes.

Comment: yes , you need to have Certificate Licence to use such Permissions.

Comment: What are the criteria for certificate license, can be be taken for individual?

Comment: First of all tell me why you are not accepting the answer, if it is useful for you ?

Comment: Really i m not aware of that till now,just i looked then found how to accept it ! Thats why till now i haven't accepted the question! any way thanks for informing!

Comment: you welcome Sagar. Just keep sharing knowledge. This site is for that purpose only

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6569/discussion-between-srizan-sagar-and-arjun)

Comment: you are always welcome to this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/  , we will talk after 4 pm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I am also trying same, I went to some extent.
Yes is possible to do ,with help of Push reg which is with MIDP 2.0 Mobile app can be called after every 10 sec or so (I didn't Coded this yet) 
and. to hide app use this line Display.getDisplay (this).setCurrent (null);
it will run be shown with your tab or run app again. 

I am still getting some problems like, Internet will Go Off when Mobile screen goes Off.